# How is horsepower measured for aviation piston engines?

Tags: piston-engine, measurement

As far as I can tell, aviation piston engine power output is typically measured in HP (horsepower).

Automotive engine power output is typically measured by running the host vehicle on a [rolling road, or dyno or dynamometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamometer).  This directly produces a torque curve, which may be integrated with respect to RPM to provide a power curve.

Obviously it wouldn't make much sense to put a piston-engined aircraft on such a device.  Instead, how is horsepower measured for aviation piston engines?

Comment: You can put engines on a dyno hooked up to the shaft directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like anything else a [Dynamometer is used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamometer) except the engine is bolted directly to it ([most likely on a test bench](http://www.nevadaaircraftengines.com/dynometer.html)). In a car a rolling road is simply a way to couple the tires to the dyno without having to have any custom fittings. For what its worth cars lose a bit of horse power in the transmission/drive shaft/differential so shaft horse power and wheel horsepower are not always the same. However in a plane the prop is bolted more or less to the end of the crank (with the exception of some planes with stepper gear boxes). In any case shaft horsepower on a plane engine is more or less whats available at the prop.

Here is a lycoming engine on a dyno

[image]

([source](http://www.nevadaaircraftengines.com/dynometer.html))

Comment: Also, long before the first engine is installed in a car on the assembly line, various pre-production examples are run on a dyno in exactly the same fashion.

Answer (score 1):

*How is horsepower measured for aviation piston engines?*

One idea is to use a ["shaft power meter"](http://www.km.kongsberg.com/ks/web/nokbg0240.nsf/AllWeb/ECC998CE82FE3801C125758300448E97?OpenDocument).

Comment: Measuring it is one thing, but you actually have to absorb the power output somehow. And spinning a big propeller in a small room is not the best way of doing this.